# How do I set a Powershell script to run a command and then run it again with a different filepath

Tags: powershell

I am using an a fileshare scanner (Trufflehog, https://github.com/trufflesecurity/trufflehog) to scan for passwords. What I want to do is create a powershell script to run the same command but changing the file directory when it finishes.

Here is the command I am using:

.\trufflehog filesystem \path\to\dir\ --no-update --json --include-detectors='AWS,okta,terraformcloudpersonaltoken,privatekey,nugetapikey,microsoftteamswebhook,ldap,github,githubapp,ftp,azure,auth0oauth,auth0managementapitoken' --fail >> newnew.json

This command works but I want to be able to add set a list of \path\to\dir so I can scan the whole fileshare instead of running the command on every filepath.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of directories from a root directory (here C:\temp) this way

```
$allpath = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Then run the command for each folders by replacing your path by "$_"

```
$allpath | ForEach-Object { .\trufflehog filesystem $_ --no-update --json --include-detectors='AWS,okta,terraformcloudpersonaltoken,privatekey,nugetapikey,microsoftteamswebhook,ldap,github,githubapp,ftp,azure,auth0oauth,auth0managementapitoken' --fail >> newnew.json }
```